# How to get only digit using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the row for controls that can have ids like the one below (generated by asp.net webform).

```
id="contentMain__lvTSEntry__tbxMinute_1"
```

I'm trying to see if I can capture just the digit, so I'm using the below javascript.

```
if (e.id.indexOf("_tbxMinute") != -1) {                        
    if (parseInt(e.value) > 59) {
       var cid = e.id;
       var patt = '\d+'
       var test = cid.match(patt)
       alert(test)
      }
```

So far I'm getting **null**. How do I get digit from the control id?

Thanks for helping

Comment: `e.id.indexOf("_tbxMinute")` or `e.id.indexOf("_tbxHour")`?

Comment: @Mario, I made a mistake that I just corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your pattern string from `var patt = '\d+'` to `var patt = '\\d+'` it should work (My try at jsfiddle did it)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
/contentMain__lvTSEntry__tbxHour_(\d+)/
```

It captures the digit:

```
> var regex = /contentMain__lvTSEntry__tbxHour_(\d+)/;
> regex.exec("contentMain__lvTSEntry__tbxHour_1")[1]
"1"
```

Alternatively, you could just use `/(\d+)/` as the entire regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove any non digit characters

```
"contentMain__lvTSEntry__tbxHour_1".replace(/\D/g,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, that returns all numbers in array:

```
function returnNumbers(string){
    return string.match(/\d+/g);
}
```

Examples:

```
> returnNumbers('123asd123')
["123", "123"]

> returnNumbers('contentMain__lvTSEntry__tbxMinute_1')
["1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `patt` as a regular expression, you should declare it as a `RegExp` type:

`var patt = /\d+/;`

`patt instanceof RegExp; // true`

`var patt = '\d+'` implies that patt is `d+`, because `\d` is translated to `d` as `\` is an escape character. Then, `match` will receive `d+` instead of `\d+` as argument.